# Is signing G-d's Holy name in casual conversation a violation of mentioning His name in vain?

Tags: halacha, translation, shemos-sacred-names, deaf

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch (6:3) writes:

> אסור להוציא שם שמים לבטלה וכל המוציא שם שמים לבטלה עובר על מצות עשה
>   דכתיב את ה' אלהיך תירא ... **ולא לבד בלשון הקודש אסור אלא אפילו בכל
>   לשון אסור**
>
> It is forbidden to say G-d's name (lit. ''the Heavenly Name'') in
>   vain, and everyone who says G-d's name in vain transgresses a positive
>   commandment, as it is written: ''The Lord your G-d you shall fear;''
>   ... It is not just in (Hebrew) the Holy Tongue, that (mentioning the
>   Name) is forbidden, but even **in any language** it is forbidden.

In this context of stating "any" language, is this restricted to verbal language, or is sign language included?

Comment: I read your title as "singing" at least 4 times.

Comment: @danf how In general is sign language viewed halachically? I'm assuming it does not have a halachic status as a language

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1317/5514

Comment: @Mefaresh - I have to research a source, but I believe that it may actually be considered a language. It has grammar and syntax and it is the way the deaf communicate.

Comment: From the gemara, sign language is considered "remizah" and does not possess the normative oral component of any other language. Proof of this is that you don't "write" sign language - sign is just a method of communicating in some OTHER language adapted for the specific method of conveyance. If that's true, then it is ***at most*** equivalent to writing Shem Hashem, and perhaps less so due to it's temporal nature. Chazal make explicit that there is a unique "koach halashon" - this doesn't translate to other forms of communication.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky You could write in sign language if you come up with glyphs to represent various movements. Why does writing define something as being a language or not, anyway?

Comment: @doubleaa it doesn't. But it's proof that sign language isn't independent of English (for asl, anyhow) any more than braille is a different language. It's just another means of conveying English.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky - The entire definition of "cheresh" has changed since the time of the gemara. In particular, in time of gemarah every "cheresh" was assumed to be a BOTH mute and deaf, and every deaf person was automatically assumed to be mute and, furthermore, non-communicative. That has changed, and, I believe that sign language is considered a valid "language" as English, perhaps, even halachically. Please be patiemt as I research this further. I'm quite certain that I saw something on this about a yr ago, but I have to hunt for it.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky - "It's just another means of conveying English" - This statement is absolutely false. I know some ASL, and I can tell you that ASL, in a sense, originated from a French form of sign language! Regardless, the grammar of ASL does NOT conform to English grammar for the most part. It has its own grammar. Look it up on the web, you'll get a better explanation than I can expound on here.

Comment: @DanF I am perfectly aware of the syntactical differences between asl and English. I learned to sign in elementary school. Remizah isn't considered language by the gemara, even though it IS considered communication. And you're entirely wrong about the definition of cheresh - the gemara makes clear distinctions between deaf and mute, but in general deals with the halachic category of deafmute when talking about cheresh. See chagiga for the story of Trei Ilmei and the Drashos on Hakhel where they distinguish between deaf, mute, and deafmute. Kiddushin by a chereshes: "kones biremizah"

Comment: @Danf what matters for this question isn't whether sign language fits the MODERN definition of a language (which it clearly DOES), but whether it fits HALACHICALLY, which is entirely different.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky understood. That's the source I have to research. I believe that the article addresses this. I think one of the items mentioned relates to using ASL for davening and perhaps even Torah reading.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Your last comment is accurate. Your whole comparison to English and to writing systems seems irrelevant and inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

If it is forbidden to *speak* God's name in vain, and it is forbidden to desecrate God's name in the *writing* of any language (MB  85:10), then it seems obvious that it is forbidden to irreverently sign God in conversation. The simple idea is about the respect we give in referring to our Creator.

Nevertheless, if you wanted to look down the pilpul glass, then it's important to note that the issue of determining the status of sign language as a halakhic language is an evolving one. This question has particular contemporary significance for the religious participation of deaf people. A good introduction into the changing status of how halakha understands sign language is a [responsum written last year](http://www.rudermanfoundation.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/IDI-Marriage-in-Sign-Language.pdf) by R. Benjamin Lau on conducting weddings for the deaf. He argues that the advances and sophistication of modern sign language perforce changes the status of deaf people from that of feeble-mindedness, as understood during the Talmudic Era, to that of intelligence. In doing this, R. Lau argues that sign language should now be considered a full language, and he quotes other authorities who agree with him (such as Chief Rabbi of Israel David Lau) and those who do not consider sign language a natural, normal language (R. Yaakov Ariel).

So at the moment, while there is not a consensus as to the halakhic status of sign language as a language, it seems to be evolving toward greater recognition. Perhaps this prevents us from answering the question (although I still believe the spirit of the halakha should be accounted for here).

P.S. As someone who studied sign language, I personally find that it completely parallels speech in terms of communication. In ASL, the word God is, like spoken English, a general term used by many kinds of religious and secular people (as opposed to the Jewish term HaShem). In Hebrew sign language, the word for HaShem is made pointing the index finger upward toward the sky. This recalls the signing used in the Talmud (Br. 48a):

> אביי ורבא הוו יתבי קמיה דרבה, אמר להו רבה: למי מברכין? אמרי ליה: לרחמנא. - ורחמנא היכא יתיב? רבא אחוי לשמי טללא, אביי נפק לברא אחוי כלפי שמיא.
>
> Abaye and Rava, when they were children, were seated before Rabba. Raba said to them: To whom does one recite blessings? They said to him: To the All Merciful. Rabba asked them: And where does the All-Merciful reside? Rava pointed to the ceiling. Abaye went outside and pointed toward the heaven.

Comment: Aryeh - thanks. I'll try to view your link, later. I am familiar with the ASL term for G-d; there are a few variants, BTW. I'm not too fluent in ASL, but I asked this Q as my son is deaf.

Comment: @DanF: From what I know, the most common ASL sign looks like a cross with one hand. So many Jews either wave a hand across the sky or point toward the sky. It is perhaps unsurprising that most sign languages, like Spanish, French, German, Ukrainian, etc. make the same pointed movement upwards. Israeli Sign Language was mostly developed from the German system, and thus also has pointing upwards.

Comment: I don't know ISL (Israeli), but I'll ask my son as he knows some ISL, also. BTW, are you deaf or hearing impaired?

Comment: No, I just love the language. I first started learning it to communicate with my daughter when she was born (you can communicate baby sign language way before children reach speaking age), and remained interested.