# PTiJ: How should animals pray?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

As it states in Tehillim 150:6:

> כֹּל הַנְּשָׁמָה, תְּהַלֵּל יָהּ:            הַלְלוּ-יָהּ. (*Kol Han'shamah t'halel Yah! Hallelu Yah!)*

It very clearly specifies "everything that breathes" so animals are certainly included in this obligation. But, the majority of animals do not have the linguistic capability of articulating all the phonemes of Hebrew. (Although dogs might not have difficulty pronouncing "baaaaaaRUCH", I don't think I could say as much for other words!)

How can animals incapable of speaking Hebrew praise God as they are commanded?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Perek Shirah...?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Yup! See the end of my answer.

Comment: If Purim is in two weeks it does not mean every question should be PTIJ. It's a legit serious question.

Comment: True, I could have phrased it as a serious question, but I am looking for PTiJ answers (like @Aaron’s).

Comment: The example of a dog pronouncing “baruch” can be confused with a sheep’s pronunciation.

Comment: Yes, although sheep cannot pronounce the “ruch” part!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Due to their limitations of speech, Animals have a custom to only pray the silent Amidah.

Comment: But what about kavannah?

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi They have intense Kavannah. It's not highly publicized but God only spared Ninveh because of the devotion of prayer from the animals. Jonah3:6-10

Answer (score 3):

I am a bear. I am smarter than the average bear. I can read. I can write. But you are right. I can not talk. Yet.

But I will learn and then I will talk and then I will pray. I know this because I read what you read.

> כֹּל הַנְּשָׁמָה, תְּהַלֵּל יָהּ:‏

All breathers *will* praise God ... someday. In the future. That means me. I will pray in the future. Not now.

Every day I pray for that day to come. Did you read [my favorite song](https://www.sefaria.org/Perek_Shirah.5.14?lang=bi) in [Perek Shirah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perek_Shirah)?

> דֹּב אוֹמֵר יִשְׂאוּ מִדְבָּר וְעָרָיו חֲצֵרִים תֵּשֵׁב קֵדָר יָרֹנּוּ ישְׁבֵי סֶלַע מֵרֹאשׁ הָרִים יִצְוָחוּ: (ישעיה מב יא)‏
>
> The Bear is saying: “Let the wilderness and its cities lift up their voice, the village that Kedar inhabits; let the inhabitants of the rocks sing, let them shout from the peaks of the mountains. Let them give kavod to YHVH, and tell of his praise in the islands.”

You see that? I live on rocks. That is me. I will sing and shout for God. Some day.

Right now I can not sing or shout. Also I am [annoyed](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100411/ptij-what-do-you-people-want). I have a not-favorite song too. Also I just woke up and I am hungry. Are you a real bunny?

Comment: Unfortunately, the bunny that is my namesake is made of cloth and stuffing. Please don’t eat it!

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/61209/5275) that indicates that sign language is a valid form of communication in halacha. (On a serious level, my son is deaf, and I have attended many Shabbatonim and events where davening is done almost exclusively using sign language. There are quite a number of halachic articles on this topic.)

Almost all animals emit various forms of sign language. A dog wagging its tail is usually happy. A cat that crouches and has its ears pointed indicates fear and defense. There are numerous ways that each animal can pray using its own sign language. This is not a problem.

On a slightly serious note - doesn't Pereke Shira convey the idea that all animals sing praises to G-d each day? How are they doing this?

Comment: Good answer! I was at a NFTY (American Reform Jewish youth movement) shabbaton a couple months ago and we prayed through the Amidah with sign language.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 are you deaf?

Comment: No, but we all found it an enlightening and holy experience just the same.