# PTIJ: What do you people want?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Yes?

Yes? I am Misha. Can I help you?

Yes? Yes? Yes? Yes? Yes?!?

**What, already?**

*Every year ... Every single year ... right **before** my alarm was set to wake me from hibernation! Grrrr ...*

#### What do you want from me???

*It sounds like singing, but they're calling ... calling ... calling my name ...*

### Grrrrr.... WHAT?!?!?

[*"Misha, Misha, Misha, Misha, Misha, Misha"*](https://youtu.be/Z5SHCRB0_NM) Why???

## WHAT DO YOU PEOPLE WANT? TELL ME ALREADY OR STOP CALLING MY NAME!

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: We want you to just enter Adar, dude. If you'd enter Adar, we'd leave you alone.

Comment: related https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3490/a-silly-question-doth-not-a-purim-torah-post-make/3794#comment11373_3794

Comment: @Y  e  z That sounds like an answer.

Comment: @Y  e  z Why is it so important that he go into Adar?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have a whole slew of achievements to your name that few can match.

> מִי שֶׁבֵּרַךְ אֲבותֵינוּ אַבְרָהָם יִצְחָק וְיַעֲקב. ... וּמִי שֶׁמְּיַחֲדִים בָּתֵּי כְנֵסִיּות לִתְפִלָּה. וּמִי שֶׁבָּאִים בְּתוכָם לְהִתְפַּלֵּל. וּמִי שֶׁנּותְנִים נֵר לַמָּאור וְיַיִן לְקִדּוּשׁ וּלְהַבְדָּלָה וּפַת לְאורְחִים וּצְדָקָה לָעֲנִיִּים. ‏
>
> Misha blessed our fathers, Abraham, Isaac and Jacob. ... Misha dedicates synagogues for prayer, and Misha comes into them to pray, and Misha gives candles for light, and wine for *kidush* and *havdala*, and bread for guests and charity for the poor!

The cries of *Misha, Misha, Misha...* tend to start on the Shabbat on which we bless the coming month of Adar, and we tell you then exactly what we want from you.

> מִי שֶׁעָשָׂה נִסִּים לַאֲבותֵינוּ וְגָאַל אותָם מֵעַבְדוּת לְחֵרוּת הוּא יִגְאַל אותָנוּ בְּקָרוב
>
> Misha did miracles for our fathers, and redeemed them from slavery to freedom. May he redeem us soon!

Not a small task, but if anyone can do it, it's Misha!

So, as we were saying: Misha, Misha, Misha, Misha, Misha, Misha, Misha, Misha, Misha, Adar is coming! Misha, Misha, Misha, Misha, Misha, Misha, Misha, Misha, Misha, Adar is coming! Misha, Adar is coming! We're supposed to increase our happiness *(hint, hint)*!

Comment: I had this same direction of thought for an answer to this question while I drove carpool and came to post an answer, and found this! I'll still post the small twist I had thought of, but +1

Answer (score 5):

Well, Misha, we feel bad that you've been spending so much time stuck outside in a booth, especially while your table is in the house (Mishna Sukka 2:7):

> מי שהיה ראשו ורובו בסוכה, ושלחנו בתוך הבית
>
> Misha's head and body is in a booth, and his table is in the house.

So, we thought we should invite you inside the house. You can come in through any door you'd like!

> משנכנס אדר מרבים בשמחה
>
> Misha, come in through a door, it would make everyone happier!

Answer (score 3):

> *[Misha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misha) [nichnas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet%E2%80%93Afghan_War) [Takhar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takhar_Province). Marbin b'simcha?*
>
> Misha entered Takhar. You think we're happy?

They're waking you up to warn you they're planning a [boycott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1980_Summer_Olympics_boycott).